# Found shared references to a collection exception in grails

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have an exception from the bellow line of code:

```
  def order = new PostOrder(pOrder: "post", posts: status, children: lookupPerson().children)
```

the lookupPerson().children gives a set of 2 Child instances with different id's

The full exception is:

```
  org.hibernate.HibernateException: Found shared references to a collection: com.fyp.timeline.PostOrder.children
at com.fyp.timeline.ProfileController$$ENwi3LDE.updateStatus(ProfileController.groovy:134)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
```

I am really stuck on this. Mainly because it did used to work and randomly stopped. I have added a new user to MySql and a new database but that should not effect this one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're passing `lookupPerson().children` to the constructor of the `PostOrder` - I'm assuming that this is a collection in the `Person` class mapped with `static hasMany = [ ... ]`. So Hibernate is telling you what's happening - you're using the same collection twice. It makes sense to me that there should only be one owner of a mapped collection. Keep in mind that these aren't regular `ArrayList`s or `HashSet`s - they're Hibernate `PersistentList`s and `PersistentSet`s which implement the correct interfaces but are Hibernate-specific.

If you want to pass the collection items to the new `PostOrder`, you can copy them into a new collection, e.g.

```
def order = new PostOrder(
    pOrder: "post", posts: status,
    children: [] + lookupPerson().children)
```

However since this is likely also a mapped collection, you should be using `addToChildren`, e.g.

```
def order = new PostOrder(pOrder: "post", posts: status)
lookupPerson().children.each { order.addToChildren it }
```